# Customer Filtered by Sales Representative but Showing Invoices for all Sales Representatives

Tags: filter, tableau-api

I'm trying to replace our current AR report which shows all invoices outstanding by customer for a particular sales representative.

The issue is that each customer may have multiple sales representatives; however, since the Sales Representative ID is stored at the invoice level the report only displays that sales representatives sales to their customer.

What I would like to do is display on the AR report all invoices outstanding for all sales reps for each customer that a particular rep visits regardless of the sales representative making the sale.

So the sales rep will only see customers that he has outstanding balances with on his report but will also see other balances from that other reps may have outstanding with his customers.

How can I achieve this?

I suspect it has something to do with a parameter and creating a calculated field which lumps the sales reps for each invoice together for a customer and then doing a contains filter; but I can't figure out how to make that first calculation.

Additional Details:

```
CUSTOMER ID CUSTOMER NAME   INVOICE NO  SALESPERSON ID  AMOUNT OTSNDNG  AR BUCKET
CUST01  Customer 1  INV01   JAMES   100 31-60
CUST01  Customer 1  INV02   JAMES   100 61-90
CUST01  Customer 1  INV03   BRIAN   100 31-60
CUST01  Customer 1  INV04   MARK    100 CURRENT
CUST02  Customer 2  INV05   MARK    100 61-90
CUST02  Customer 2  INV06   JAMES   100 31-60
CUST03  Customer 3  INV07   MARK    100 31-60
CUST03  Customer 3  INV08   BRIAN   100 61-90
```

In the above table, when running an accounts receivable report for Brian Invoices 1-4 and 7-8 should show up as he sells to both of these customers. All invoices should show up on Mark's AR as he sells to all three customers and James should see the invoices for Customer 1 and 2.

I would attach a file to the question with this data in a spreadsheet if I could.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you showed how your data is organized. Explaining what AR stands for is nice to have as well

Comment: AR is almost certainly "accounts receivable".

Comment: AR = Accounts Receivable. I adjusted the original question to include a mini data set, but can't figure out table formatting or attachments so I hope it's usable.

Comment: Thanks for the additional input, now I can help

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to achieve this is using parameters and conditional filters.

First, create a parameter 'rep'. Define it as list, and import [SALESPERSON] values to it.

Now the trick part, you want to filter the clients that has ever been visited by a specific salesperson. This is how you do that on Tableau:

1- Create a calculated field [marker]. Use the formula:

```
IF [SALESPERSON] = [rep]
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Note this will basically put a 1 marker on the lines of the selected salesperson

2- Drag [CUSTOMER ID] to filter
3- Go to tab 'Condition'
4- Use By field: [marker], Sum, >, 0

This will basically run a calculation. For each customer, it will get all [marker] entries, sum all them. Those who are above zero (meaning, there is at least one 1 marker) will be kept, those who are zero are eliminated

Let me know if this doesn't work, or you have any question

Comment: Inox you beautiful beautiful soul! Worked like a charm! Just having my accounts clerk checking it back against the system to confirm.

Comment: @Steven, don't forget to accept and upvote Inox's answer so he gets a reputation boost for helping you